# Rotate an image to orient it to the center of the screen

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, rotation, center

I have an image which is at a random position every time the application is open and I want to orient it to the center of the screen (160,240), how can I do this please ? I think that I must calculate an angle and make a rotation with this angle but I'm not sure :/ sorry for my english I'm french :/

Comment: So let me get this straight, is the image the only thing that is on your view? And it doesn't stay where you placed it when you launch the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly.

If you add the UIImageView in the nib file you should just put it where you want the image to load. Then in the Size inspector make sure everything there matches what you want the image to do. If I am wrong please tell me how you implement the image and I will update my answer accordingly